# In laravel how can i run two socket servers simultaneously?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to run two different socket servers simultaneously at a time.

Details:

I have 3 technologies in one web app,

1. React Js
2. Php
3. cpp

Php is the middle one.

php (server) and cpp (client) we are communicating on the raw socket and it is working fine, But now in React (client) we also introduce the WebSocket which will communicate to php (server).
When working with react WebSocket it is kind of different like handshaking and all.

What i did:

I have a command `php artisan server:setup` which will on the server after the application launch.

Now there are 2 servers in php I call them in the handle function of that command, Now only one server is in the listening mode? I want both of them to be in listen mode when hitting the command.
Both server code is different from one another.
I have called like this in app/console/commands/command_file_name

```
public function handle()
 {
    $this->forui();
    $this->forcpp();
 }
```

Both function codes are slightly different and having different ports but the same host.

Aim:

React will send msg to PHP that i am alive, and it same from CPP
and PHP will check both parties sending the msg as a defined string and do the needful actions.

Comment: For the 2 servers in PHP, I suggest you to use two different listening port numbers and it should be fine.

Comment: Yes, i am using 2 different PORTS for that. But as i said when hitting the command want to run both servers at a time. but it is working for only one.

Comment: One question - are you using two different instance of http to execute the two PHP servers ?

Comment: No, It is one instance. I have also updated the question.

Comment: If you have time, please try to install and run another instance of http service, and then run the two PHP servers thru two separate instances on two different ports. (but you will need extra effort but it is worth the time in my opinion) Have a good day bro !

Comment: Now, i am working on localhost